# Mobile robot moving around can not visualize in RVIZ, why so?

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-humble

I have a mobile robot that is able to visualise it in Rviz. But when the robot moves it doesn't show it in rviz, only shows the laser scans, but the robot model is static. The Lidar frame id is laser_link. Here is the URDF file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="sam_bot" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Define robot constants -->
  <xacro:property name="base_width" value="0.31"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_length" value="0.42"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_height" value="0.18"/>

  <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.10"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.04"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_ygap" value="0.025"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_zoff" value="0.05"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_xoff" value="0.12"/>

  <xacro:property name="caster_xoff" value="0.14"/>

  <!-- Define some commonly used intertial properties  -->
  <xacro:macro name="box_inertia" params="m w h d">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${pi/2}"/>      
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (h*h + d*d)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(m/12) * (w*w + d*d)}" iyz="0.0" izz="${(m/12) * (w*w + h*h)}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="cylinder_inertia" params="m r h">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />      
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (3*r*r + h*h)}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0" iyy="${(m/12) * (3*r*r + h*h)}" iyz = "0" izz="${(m/2) * (r*r)}"/> 
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="sphere_inertia" params="m r">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${m}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}" iyz="0.0" izz="${(2/5) * m * (r*r)}"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
  
  <!-- Robot Base -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Cyan">
        <color rgba="0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_length} ${base_width} ${base_height}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="15" w="${base_width}" d="${base_length}" h="${base_height}"/>
  </link>
  
   <!-- Robot Footprint -->
  <link name="base_footprint">
    <xacro:box_inertia m="0" w="0" d="0" h="0"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_footprint"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 ${-(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff)}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <!-- Wheels -->
  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="prefix x_reflect y_reflect">
    <link name="${prefix}_link">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Gray">
          <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0"/>
        </material>
      </visual>

      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/> 
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="0.5" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="${prefix}_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_link"/>
      <origin xyz="${x_reflect*wheel_xoff} ${y_reflect*(base_width/2+wheel_ygap)} ${-wheel_zoff}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:wheel prefix="drivewhl_l" x_reflect="-1" y_reflect="1" />
  <xacro:wheel prefix="drivewhl_r" x_reflect="-1" y_reflect="-1" />

  <link name="front_caster">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff-(base_height/2))}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="Cyan">
        <color rgba="0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff-(base_height/2))}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="${(wheel_radius+wheel_zoff-(base_height/2))}"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="caster_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="front_caster"/>
    <origin xyz="${caster_xoff} 0.0 ${-(base_height/2)}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name='diff_drive' filename='libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so'>
      <ros>
        <namespace>/demo</namespace>
      </ros>

      <!-- wheels -->
      <left_joint>drivewhl_l_joint</left_joint>
      <right_joint>drivewhl_r_joint</right_joint>

      <!-- kinematics -->
      <wheel_separation>0.4</wheel_separation>
      <wheel_diameter>0.2</wheel_diameter>

      <!-- limits -->   
      <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
      <max_wheel_acceleration>1.0</max_wheel_acceleration>

      <!-- output -->
      <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
      <publish_odom_tf>false</publish_odom_tf>
      <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>

      <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
      <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

 <link name="laser_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.125"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.001"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0" izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder radius="0.0508" length="0.055"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder radius="0.0508" length="0.055"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
    
  <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="laser_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.12" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
    
  <gazebo reference="lidar_link">
    <sensor name="lidar" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>0.000000</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.280000</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.120000</min>
          <max>3.5</max>
          <resolution>0.015000</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="scan" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=scan</remapping>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        <frame_name>lidar_link</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
  </robot>
```

And here the launch file

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='amr_bot').find('amr_bot')
    default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/amr_bot_description.urdf')
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
    world_path=os.path.join(pkg_share, 'world/my_world.sdf')
    
    robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('model')])}]
    )
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', LaunchConfiguration('rvizconfig')],
    )
    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='gazebo_ros', 
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=['-entity', 'amr_bot', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
        output='screen'
    )
    robot_localization_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
         package='robot_localization',
         executable='ekf_node',
         name='ekf_filter_node',
         output='screen',
         parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/ekf.yaml'), {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}]
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='gui', default_value='True',
                                            description='Flag to enable joint_state_publisher_gui'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=default_model_path,
                                            description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='rvizconfig', default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
                                            description='Absolute path to rviz config file'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='use_sim_time', default_value='True',
                                            description='Flag to enable use_sim_time'),
        launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', world_path], output='screen'),
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        spawn_entity,
        robot_localization_node,
        rviz_node
    ])
```

This is the frame three [image: tf_three]

This the Robot Model , TF and Laser Scans in Rviz [image: Rviz showing the Robot Model]
Can anyone help show the robot moving around in RVIZ?

Comment: Did you try adding a robot model and TF displays in Rviz?

Comment: Yes. Done . You can see the RVIZ. But still when the real robot moves around the RViz robot model remains static . Only the laser scans are moving

Comment: What is the fixed frame in the Global options set to?

Comment: its laser_link. That is the 2D Lidar frame id

Comment: When you say "moving around" I think you mean see the map and the robot moving within the map. Your frames shows that there is no map frame or map-->odom tf. That TF is usually generated by your localization but there needs to be a map.  Is there a map? If no map and you just want to see the robot move in space, suggest try changing the fixed frame in RVIZ to ODOM.

Comment: At the moment there is no map. I just wonna see robot move in space

Comment: But when  set the fixed frame iin RVIZ to ODOM still nothing happened. Still can not see the robot move in Space

Comment: any help on this?